# How to render multiple modals in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I need to render multiple modals but the number of modals are not fixed and depend on property `audios` of the object coming in. I'm currently using the mui modal

This is the variables used:

```
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
```

And this is how I attempt to render the modals. Currently, the modal that opens after clicking 'view' only shows the last value in `audios` no matter which 'View' button I click on

```
  {audios.map((a) => (
          <Grid item container justifyContent="flex-end">
            <Button
              onClick={handleOpen}
              sx={{
                color: 'blue',
                marginTop: '0.6rem',
              }}
            >
              View
            </Button>
            <Modal
              open={open}
              onClose={handleClose}
            >       
              <Box
                sx={{
                  position: 'absolute' as 'absolute',
                  top: '50%',
                  left: '50%',
                  p: 4,
                }}
              >
            <Typography color='white'>{a.name}</Typography>
              </Box>
            </Modal>
          </Grid>
        ))}
```

Is there way to have separate state for open and close for each modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       const MyModalandButton=()=>{
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
      const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
    return <>
             <Button
              onClick={handleOpen}
              sx={{
                color: 'blue',
                marginTop: '0.6rem',
              }}
            >
              View
            </Button>
             <Modal
              open={open}
              onClose={handleClose}
            >  </>  
    }
```

maybe just like this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think u should put the 'open' state in the Modal component , by this way every Modal have their own state .

Comment: but then what would I pass in to the Button? since it also needs a `handleOpen` and `handleOpen` uses `open`. Would appreciate any code example!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).